# Matching text strings to a set of keywords/categories (R)

Tags: r, nlp

I am trying to identify which functional area a role title belongs to based on a set of keywords identified for each function.

I have a list of roles (sample - not exhaustive)

```
> roles
 [1] "Senior Financial Analyst"        
 [2] "IT Intern"                       
 [3] "IT Analyst"                      
 [4] "Financial Analyst"               
 [5] "Data Analyst"                    
 [6] "Finance Co-op"                   
 [7] "FLDP Associate Financial Analyst"
 [8] "Talent Acquisition Coordinator"  
 [9] "Senior Tax Analyst"              
[10] "Finance Manager"                 
[11] "Software Engineer"               
[12] "Software Developer"              
[13] "Talent Acquisition"
```

and a list of keywords for each function (showing 3 for reference - Finance, HR and IT). For some keywords partial matches are fine but for other the exact text is required. In some instances the keywords may not be mutually exclusive as well.

```
> finance
[1] "Financ"     "Accountant" "Tax"        "Receivable"
[5] "Reporting"  "Accounting" "Collection"
> hr
[1] "/\bHR\b/"      "Human Resourc" "Talent"       
[4] "Training"      "Recruit"       "Learn"        
[7] "Workforce"     "/\bEHS/\b"     "Employ"       
> it
[1] "/\bIT\b/"   "Informatic" "Software"   "/\bSAP\b/" 
[5] "Architect"  "Data Manag" "Data Ware"  "Digital"   
[9] "Scrum"
```

What I want to be able to do is match each role title to the 'best fit' function based on the entire list of keywords. The Result should be a dataframe with `roles` in column 1 and a `return.function` (in this case either `Finance` `HR` `IT` or `No Match`) in column 2 - single match for each role tile or `No Match` if appropriate). Bonus if column 3 could contain a level of confidence in the assignment of a function but not absolutely necessary.

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   roles                            return.function match.p            
   <fct>                            <fct>           <fct>              
 1 Senior Financial Analyst         finance         Level of Confidence
 2 IT Intern                        it              Level of Confidence
 3 IT Analyst                       it              Level of Confidence
 4 Financial Analyst                finance         Level of Confidence
 5 Data Analyst                     No Match        Level of Confidence
 6 Finance Co-op                    finance         Level of Confidence
 7 FLDP Associate Financial Analyst finance         Level of Confidence
 8 Talent Acquisition Coordinator   hr              Level of Confidence
 9 Senior Tax Analyst               finance         Level of Confidence
10 Finance Manager                  finance         Level of Confidence
11 Software Engineer                it              Level of Confidence
12 Software Developer               it              Level of Confidence
13 Talent Acquisition               hr              Level of Confidence
```

At present I am using `quanteda` to create dictionaries and assigning a `return.function` based on the maximum number of keyword matches. Challenge with this is where counts are the same, the decision criteria becomes the first dictionary.

This is an extreme example with sparse amounts of information contained solely in a role title. Eventually I would like to increase the volume of text by including a role summary from a job description.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great question.  Have you tried coding anything yourself yet?  By the way, you should probably include the _exact_ output you expect from the above sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your suggestions. Updated the question.